# Fetch views using a ajax request

Tags: views, ajax

I worked in printing out a view using php. Is it possible to fetch views using ajax and load in the page? For suppose I have three links each one will fetch a view using ajax and load in the current page. (Am I talking sense?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is very much possible, but probably you can do it only by creating custom module.

- send Ajax request to the Drupal
- load selected view form database by [views_get_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_get_view/6)
- execute selected display by [$view->execute_display('display')](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--includes--view.inc/function/view::execute_display/6)
- send HTML created on executing display back to the client.
- on client side put this html wherever you want

Check [ajax load](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_load) module (which is D6 only) too, maybe it can help you.

There is a even quicker way and more robust to render a view: [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

Comment: I'm new to drupal 7, how do I can send ajax request to the Drupal? where must be the javascript file? and where musst be the server side code?

Comment: @Mohammad use google Luke ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following javascript code to load a view via ajax.

```
$.post(
Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
{

view_name: '<your view id>',view_display_id: '<page or block ...>',view_args: 'arg1/arg2..'
},

function(response)
{
    if (response[1] !== undefined) 
    {
        var viewHtml = response[1].data;
        $("#user_gal_photos").html(viewHtml);
       /*...*/
        Drupal.attachBehaviors();
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, however be careful with the Drupal.attachBehaviors() call at the end. It caused some problems for me. I removed it as it's not needed for my simple non-paged view.