# Attached view ajax call (lazy load) with exposed filters

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I'm using views with a main view and an attachment to put 2 views on a single page. Each view is in it's own [Bootstrap togglable tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Because I don't know how many people will actually switch to the non-default tab, I'd like to wait to load that view until it's needed, then load it via ajax.

Is there any way to do this within the Views UI, or is it time for custom coding? [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/fetch-views-using-a-ajax-request) is kind of old, but is that the best method for executing an ajax call to render a view?

**Edit:** A complicating factor is that I need to include exposed filters, which also need to fetch the data via Ajax. Right now, the filters work with the second tab, but not the first. I believe this is because Quicktabs creates multiple sections with `.view-dom-id-<settings.view_dom_id>`, which is the selector used in Views `js/ajax_view.js`.

Any solutions that work with exposed filters and Ajax?

Comment: It would be better if you use lazy load by simply following this url -- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload . Render two views content on a hook menu page and then using using above link for lazy loading in custom way.

Comment: @SugandhKhanna that plugin is for images and is not specific to Drupal ajax calls at all. Can you elaborate on how it would be used in this situation?

Comment: @nicolekanderson did you try my answer?

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm trying to work within the Quicktabs module and built-in Views ajax handling. I may try your code if I can't get that to work, but coding from scratch will likely involve a lot more work to get exposed filters and pagination working properly.

Answer (score 1):

U can use quicktab module for the same. Create Tab with it, and select your view which u want to use. After that there is an option to check how to load content of the tab, u can either choose to load at once, or on click of tab using ajax.

Comment: This module seems promising, but there are some bugs with exposed filters. @ManojBisht do you know if there's a good solution that works with exposed filters applying to both views?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the other view a page view so that they all have urls

then using the Ajax [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

```
(function ($) {
   $("#Tab1").click(function(){
     $("#Area").load("/view1URLgoesHERE");
   });
   $("#Tab2").click(function(){
     $("#Area").load("/view2URLgoesHERE");
   });
})(jQuery);
```

if you want an animated loading image add:

```
.html('<center><img src="/loading.gif"></center>').load("/view1URLgoesHERE");
```

before the `.load`